# how to change control from one html page to another in node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, node.js

I need to develop a web app for admin panel using node.js.I just learnt how to display a static html using node.js.

```
var sys = require("sys"),   
my_http = require("http");  
fs = require('fs');

my_http.createServer(function(request,response){     
fs.readFile("index.html",function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log("error occured");
    }
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content- Length':data.length});
    response.write(data);  
    response.end();     
});
}).listen(7777);  
sys.puts("Server Running on 7777");
```

But I am not able to understand how to change the view from one html page to another, like when the login button is clicked. I've used to php earlier where I give the name of the php file in the action of the form. Similarly what should be done in node.js?

Comment: Q: How did you do it in PHP?  You wrote some HTML, with an `<input>`button in a `<form>`, and the form tag had an `action=` that linked to another HTML page, didn't you?  Q: Why wouldn't you do the same with a Node.js server?  This link might help: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74559-the-nodejs-part6-form-programming/

Comment: So I would have to give the name of node.js file in the action?
I don't get it. At the beginning the node.js server file runs from the browser and I display the html home page and after that what'll happen when the submit button in the form is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

For node.js, everything from routing to redirection is to be hand-coded. You need to learn more in node.js for this. You can refer - http://www.nodebeginner.org/ site for learning.

Also if you want to use some high level library , you can go through - expressjs - http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html and may google for node express applications.

For you question -

You have to extract information from **req.url** property and then branch your code accordingly for file reading.

More of this can be found in

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url

Hope it will help you.